# How to compare a hashed password from user input?

Tags: php, hash, cryptography

I want my login password to be secured. So I came up to use the PHP's crypt() function to hash the password before inserting it to database. But Im having trouble when comparing the user input password from the converted hash password. Here's my code:

```
<?php
$password = 'hello_password';

# A higher "cost" is more secure
$cost = 10;

# Create a random salt
$salt = strtr(base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)), '+', '.');

# Blowfish algorithm. 
$salt = sprintf("$2a$%02d$", $cost) . $salt;
$salted_password = $password . $salt;  // apply salt to password

# hash the password
$hash_password = hash('sha256', $salted_password);

$userInput = 'hello_password';  // suppose this is the user input password 

if (hash('sha256',$userInput) == $password) {
    echo "Password Verified.";
}
else {
    echo "Incorrect Password";
}
```

?>

But it always displays Incorrect Password although my password is correct. I don't want to use "hash_equals" function as it is not supported with my current PHP version. Can someone help me with this ? Thanks

Comment: You need to encrypt the user inputted password the exact same way you did when you stored it. Otherwise how is `hash(mcrypt(PASSWORD));` going to match `hash(PASSWORD);` ?

Comment: you mean using the mcrypt function before comparing ?

Comment: I mean you need to do the exact same encryption to the user input as to what you did with the one stored in the database.

Comment: can you show me how please? Thanks

Comment: you compare to the raw password (`$password`), not the hashed one (`$hash_password`)

Comment: Don't forget to store the salt in the database.

Comment: I tried to store the salt in the database but when I compare the user input and the stored password, it did not match. Why ?

Answer (score 2):

You're comparing a hashed user input to the actual user password.  So of course this is never going to work.

You're basically asking if hash == 'hello_password'.  A hash will never match that, that is the whole point of a hash.  You also aren't using the salt with the user input.

You hash the actual password with a salt which is fine:

```
$salted_password = $password . $salt;  // apply salt to password

# hash the password
$hash_password = hash('sha256', $salted_password);
```

So you need to hash the user input with the salt, the same way:

```
$salted_input = $userInput . $salt;  // apply salt to user input

# hash the input
$hash_input = hash('sha256', $salted_input);
```

Then you can compare `$hash_input` with `$hash_password`.

You also aren't using a salt properly.  The salt is supposed to be used in the storage of the password to prevent rainbow table attacks.  Randomly generating a salt to apply to both the input and the password at the time of comparison is pointless.

Comment: You're missing the fact that he is actually `hash()`'ing the user input but he doesn't do the whole `strtr(base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)), '+', '.');` thing to the user input...

Comment: @Darren yeah, that is used to generate the salt though, it has nothing to do with the hash.  Although, I'm not sure why he is using a salt at all because it seems pointless since it isn't used to store the password.

Comment: Touche @Devon, It's too early for me to be up haha! I reckon you should show him a little snippet of best practice in doing this kind of stuff ;)

Comment: Can you show me the best practice of using salt ? I have really no idea I just found some of that code and test it my own. Please correct my code above. Thanks

Comment: @Larcy how are you storing the password?  Read up on rainbow table attacks to find the reason for salts.   Salts and hashes are usually used in databases, you store the hash and the salt in two separate columns per user.  Therefore you never store the plain text password.

Comment: Isn't it vulnerable to hackers when I store the plain text password in the database? As what I've read, the password must be converted into a hash then stored it in the database.